# inserting file from frame

Tags: java, file

If i don't enter any details and click the save and continue button, the label l4 should change to "no record entered"... but it doesn't happen like that and when i view the file it has some data inside it.
so here's the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
class frameExe extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("student.txt");
PrintStream p=new PrintStream(fos);
FileReader fr=new FileReader("student.txt");
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
int m1,m2;
Label l1,l2,l3,l4;
TextField t1,t2,t3;
TextArea ta1;
Button b1,b2,b3;
int total;
int avg;
String lines,details="";
public frameExe() throws Exception
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    l1= new Label("name");
    l2= new Label(" mark1");
    l3= new Label("mark2");
    l4= new Label("details");
    t1=new TextField(20);
    t2=new TextField(5);
    t3=new TextField(5);
    ta1=new TextArea(20,60);
    b1=new Button("save & calculate the total");
    b2=new Button("clear");
    b3=new Button("Exit");
    add(l1);
    add(t1);
    add(l2);
    add(t2);
    add(l3);
    add(t3);
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(b3);
    add(l4);
    add(ta1);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if(ae.getSource()==b1)//save and continue button
    {
        if(((t1.getText())==null)||((t1.getText())=="")||((t1.getText())==" "))
        l4.setText("no record entered");// this is not working
else
{
        p.print("name = ");
        p.print(t1.getText());
        p.print("  mark1 = ");
        p.print(t2.getText());
        p.print("  mark2 = ");
        p.print(t3.getText());
        m1=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
        m2=Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());
        total=m1+m2;
        avg=total/2;
        p.print("  total = ");
        p.print(total);
        p.print("  average = ");
        p.println(avg);
        t1.setText("");
        t2.setText("");
        t3.setText("");
        try
        {
            while((lines=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                details+=lines;
                details+='\n';
            }
            ta1.setText(details);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error "+e);
        }
}//else block ending
    }
    if(ae.getSource()==b2)//clear button
    {
        t1.setText("");
        t2.setText("");
        t3.setText("");
    }
    if(ae.getSource()==b3)// exit button
    {
        frameExe.this.dispose();
    }
}
public static void main(String s[])throws Exception
{
    frameExe f= new frameExe();
    f.setSize(400,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor bug in your code. Must be like

```
if(t1.getText().isEmpty()||t2.getText().isEmpty()||t3.getText().isEmpty()) {
    l4.setText("no record entered");
}
```

`t1.getText()` never return null because

> java.​awt.​TextComponent#getText() 
>     
> Returns
>   the text that is presented by this text component. By default, this is
>   an empty string.

You must read [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **t1.getText()).equals( "")** rather than t1.getText()) ==""